# IEnumerable & IEnumerator

Tags: .net, interface

Can anyone please explain to me what is the difference between IEnumerable & IEnumerator , 
and how to use them?

Thanks!!!

Comment: On what language / platform ?

Comment: That'll be .NET - have retagged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, an `IEnumerable` is an object which can be enumerated, such as a list or array. An `IEnumerator` is an object that stores the state of the enumeration.

The reason they're not one and the same is that you could have multiple enumerations over the same object at the same time - even in a single-threaded application. For example, consider the following code:

```
foreach (x in mylist)
{
    foreach (y in mylist)
    {
        if (x.Value == y.Value && x != y)
        {
            // Found a duplicate value
        }
    }
}
```

This would work fine if `mylist` is a proper implementation of `IEnumerable`, but it would fail if `mylist` returned itself as the enumerator.

Comment: I think an sample implementation of IEnumerator would help the OP. It's much clearer once you see how those two play along..

Answer (score 10):

The `IEnumerable` interface defines a class which can be enumerated over, i.e. it contains elements which can be accessed through enumeration.

The `IEnumerator` interfaces defines a class which can perform enumeration over a sequence of elements.

The distinction is that `IEnumerable` means "you can enumerate me", where `IEnumerator` performs the task of enumeration.

To elaborate a little more, `IEnumerable` exposes a method `GetEnumerator`. This method returns an `IEnumerator` you can then use to perform the enumerating. Normally you don't deal with this method yourself, because the `foreach` keyword handles it for you.

```
foreach(int element in myList)
{
    // Do some work...
}
```

This code is actually expanded for you by the compiler into this:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = myList.GetEnumerator();
try 
{
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
   {
      int element = (int)enumerator.Current;
      // Do some work...
   }
}
finally 
{
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

As you can see, an `IEnumerator` is used here to perform the enumeration through the elements.

Answer (score 3):

An `IEnumerable` is something that can be enumerated. An `IEnumerator` is the means to do that enumeration. So `IEnumerable` defines just one method - `GetEnumerator`, which returns an instance of `IEnumerator` to do the actual legwork...

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` defines an object which contains an aggregation of objects, which can be enumerated.

`IEnumerator` is the object which allows the aggregation to be enumerated, and stores the state of the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable means something that can be enumerated, IEnumerator is something that enumerates it.

Simplifying it to a simple for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
   count+=myarray[i];
}
```

In the example above, i would be IEnumerator, and myarray would be IEnumerable.

Comment: That is not correct - i is simply an `int`, it does not implement `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerator.

1. IEnumerable uses IEnumerator internally.
2. IEnumerable doesn’t know which item/object is executing.
3. IEnumerator knows the current position of item/object.
4. IEnumerable doesn't know the current position of item/object
5. IEnumerable has one method, GetEnumerator ()

Get Code-[IEnumerable & IEnumerator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-ienumerable-and-ienumerator)

```
public class Program {  
    public static void Main(string[] args) {  
        IEnumerable_Example();  
    }  
    static void IEnumerable_Example() {  
        List < string > Month = new List < string > ();  
        Month.Add("January");  
        Month.Add("February");  
        Month.Add("March");  
        Month.Add("April");  
        Month.Add("May");  
        Month.Add("June");  
        Month.Add("July");  
        Month.Add("August");  
        Month.Add("September");  
        Month.Add("October");  
        Month.Add("November");  
        Month.Add("December");  
        IEnumerable < string > IEnumerable_ = (IEnumerable < string > ) Month;  
        Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable_Example() Executing");  
        Console.WriteLine("------------IEnumerable Returning items using foreach----------------");  
        foreach(string i in IEnumerable_) {  
            Console.WriteLine(i);  
        }  
        IEnumerator_Example(IEnumerable_);  
    }  
    static public void IEnumerator_Example(IEnumerable enumerable) {  
        IEnumerator enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();  
        Console.WriteLine("----------IEnumerator_Example() Executing------------");  
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {  
            Console.WriteLine("----" + enumerator.Current.ToString() + "----");  
        }
```